# Find first five users with highest points

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an **Invitee** model which `belongs_to :event` and `has_many :analytics` with a column **points** in which all points are stored

**Event** model which `has_many :invitees` and `has_many :analytics`

**Analytic** model which `belongs_to :event`

In analytic model I've defined some action_points like for comment he will get 2 points for rating 5 points

```
ACTION_POINTS = {"favorite" => 5, "rated" => 5, "comment" => 2, "conversation post" => 5, "like" => 2}
```

I want to get those first five invitees who get 1000 points first - for this what I've done so far is

In my invitee model I created a method on after update and also added a time field **invitee_points_time**

```
after_update :update_time, if: -> { points == 1000}

scope :thousand_points, -> { where(points: '1000').order('invitee_points_time DESC') }

def update_time
  self.update_column('invitee_points_time', Time.now)
end
```

and then I was thinking of getting those five invitees with highest times. But the problem is arising on existing invitees which already have points more then 1000 and I also want to get list of those five invitees with points who got 1000 points first.
And yes It should be like from events e.g `Event.last.invitee.analytics`
Please tell me if I forget to mention something.

To get the list of old invitees with points I did this

```
Analytic.select("invitee_id, sum(points) as sum_points").where(:invitee_id => Event.find(364).invitees.pluck(:id)).group(:invitee_id).having("sum_points > 1000").map{|a| [a.invitee_id, a.sum_points]}
```

This is what I got

```
[[8358, 1929], [11326, 1340], [11328, 1200], [11358, 1042], [11366, 2699], [11377, 11737], [11415, 7968], [11421, 1398], [11429, 1965], [11437, 1750], [11443, 54928], [11447, 3052], [11448, 28045], [11449, 2846], [11455, 3436], [11457, 40937], [11458, 32163], [11460, 2179], [11935, 2784]]
```

But I don't really understand how to find out from them(old records) and from new records which 5 invitees reaches to first 1000 points.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In general its better to add the code itself in a question rather than trying to describe what said code does. It also helps if someone is willing to reproduce and test the issue. So please add your models (or at least the relevant portions). Also for SQL questions you should show an example of the expected output.

Comment: Edited post with my query to get list of records which already have points more then 1000

Comment: How do you plan to differentiate between old and new invitees?

Comment: do you have timestamps (`created_at` and `updated_at` columns) on your invitees table ?

Comment: @max that is where i'm stuck I am not getting any idea how to include old invitee points in list.

Comment: @sa77 Yes but points in invitee come from analytics so I don't think created_at and updated_at columns of invitees has to do anything with it.(but yea offcourse I can be wrong)

Comment: okay .. then i'm assuming you also have timestamps on your analytics table .. if you do .. then you can just run a query on your analytics table  with `updated_at` order the list in `desc` and get the first 5 records.

Comment: @sa77 Invitee has many analytics ?? So simple query not possible